# Query for EventId's that match multiple TagId's

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a many to many table that holds both EventId and TagId.

```
+-------+---------+
| TagId | EventId |
+-------+---------+
|   150 |   61096 |
|   149 |   61096 |
|   149 |   61095 |
+-------+---------+
```

How can I query for only EventId's that match both TagId 149 and TagId 150?

Desired result:

```
+---------+
| EventId |
+---------+
|   61096 |
+---------+
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything???

Answer (score 0):

This works for finding the events that have at least these two tags:

```
SELECT EventId
FROM Events_Tags
WHERE TagId IN (149, 150)
GROUP BY EventId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TagId) = 2;
```

Comment: Assuming that the combination of TagId and EventId is unique then both queries do exactly the same thing: "find the events that have at least these two tags".

Comment: This includes the case of duplicates https://dbfiddle.uk/9sSYud5i

Comment: `COUNT (DISTINCT TagId)` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using :

```
SELECT EventId
FROM Events_Tags
WHERE TagId IN (149, 150)
GROUP BY EventId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN TagId = 149 then 1 end) = 1  AND COUNT(CASE WHEN TagId = 149 then 1 end) = 1;
```

Or simply :

```
SELECT EventId
FROM Events_Tags
WHERE TagId IN (149, 150)
GROUP BY EventId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TagId) = 2;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/eZfiENGF)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT EventId
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING (EventId)
WHERE t1.TagId = 149
  AND t2.TagId = 150
```

If `(EventId, TagId)` is unique then DISTINCT not needed.